# ¿Cómo empezar una carta de manera formal/oficial?

Tags: traducción, formalidad, correspondencia

Tengo que escribir una carta formal y quiero escribir de la misma manera y con el mismo respeto que en inglés (dear sir, dear madam), son dos personas que no son parientes pero quiero ser cortés con ellos en mi carta.

Creo que lo mejor es: "Querido señor, querida señora" pero no se si es lo mejor y si puedo hablar como así en español.
Lo siento si es difícil entender lo que dijo, no he practicado mi español desde mucho tiempo.

---

How to start a formal letter with an equivalent to: "Dear Sir, dear Madam"

I'm having to type a formal letter and I'd like to know how to address two unrelated people, one gentleman and a lady whilst retaining as much as possible a sense of politeness when addressing them, preferably in a similar form to: "Dear Sir, dear Madam" in english.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normalmente, la fórmula correcta formal de dirigirse por carta suele ser:

> Estimados señores:

No te preocupes si te parece muy "masculino", puesto que "señores" indica hombres y mujeres (señores y señoras). Si sabes si a quien te diriges es hombre o mujer, entonces puedes usar "estimado señor" o "estimada señora".

También se suele usar:

> Muy señores nuestros:

o "muy señor mío" o "muy señora mía" en el caso en que conozcas si es hombre o mujer. Sin embargo, esta fórmula puede ser incluso demasiado formal hoy en día si se utiliza en un correo electrónico, ya que el propio carácter de los email es algo informal.

Por último, fíjate que al final de la frase se pone dos puntos (:) y no una coma (,) como sucede en inglés.